# How can I make divs under a fixed div not scrollable?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu that collapses under a certain width.
The menu has a fixed position and I want that it covers thw whole page height and width. So I set the width and height to 100vw and 100vh.
My problem is that the content under that fixed div is scrollable. There is a way to make those div not scrollable?

This is a sample. As you can see when the mobile menu shows up it covers the whole height and it seems that content disappears
https://www.milanbergamoairport.it/en/

I can make a codepen if it is neeeded

Thanks!

Comment: Yes code is needed.... absolutely needed!!!

Comment: I have checked your website.. and by your question it's not clear that what you exactly want? Can u pls explain a bit more

Answer (score 0):

Didn't really get the full picture of your problem but adding overflow-x: hidden; overflow-x: hidden ; hides the scroll

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you mean... Maybe `overflow-y: hidden;` is what you're searching for... if not, please provide a codepen example

Comment: note that `overflow-y hidden;` prevent the scrolling on the y-axis only; if you want it to affect the x-axis as well, use `overflow: hidden;`